# php code not converting to html

Tags: php, html

I have a php code

```
<select style="width: 200px;" name="location" id="myselect" onchange="window.location='enable1.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
  <option value="All">All</option>
 <?php

  $sql="select * from location";
  var_dump($sql);
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  echo "1";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
      echo "<option value='$row[loc]'>'$row[loc]'</option>";
  }
    ?>

</select>
```

In this code i echo"options" but instead of that when I view source code I see php part written not options..

Comment: This means that the file does not get interpreted as PHP code. So the question is: how do you open it?

Comment: Show a screenshot of what you actually see.

Comment: And what about this `echo "1";`? This probably generates invalid HTML, right?

Comment: @JimGarrison The OP clearly said what he sees.

Comment: Show a screenshot please what you are viewing?

Comment: did you save file as .php, and did you run it from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysqli_fetch_array()... Try this...

```
<select style="width: 200px;" name="location" id="myselect" onchange="window.location='enable1.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
<option value="All">All</option>
 <?php

  $sql="select * from location";
  var_dump($sql);
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  echo "1";
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
      echo "<option value='$row[loc]'>'$row[loc]'</option>";
  }
    ?>

</select>
```

let me know if it helps...

Answer (score 2):

as Saedawke stated in comment, when you see php code instead of output, it means that this file is not interpreted as php but html. 
make sure that:

- you have set file type to php (.php),
- your server is running and have php support
- your file is not outside of server folder

Comment: Add also - "You are running website trough webserver, not by opening file directly in browser" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try after remove var_dump and echo "1" from your php code hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assumption is you are fetching the data.

```
<select style="width: 200px;" name="location" id="myselect" onchange="window.location='enable1.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
  <option value="All">All</option>
 <?php

  $sql="select * from location";
  var_dump($sql);
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  echo "1";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
      echo "<option value=".$row['loc'].">".$row['loc']."</option>"; //added dots
  }
    ?>

</select>
```

Comment: `echo "1";` still needs to be removed.